# SetContents SunEditor is not working React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref, suneditor

I have been testing with SunEditor since I want to pre-load an HTML text stored in DB and let users modify it if necessary. I'm passing a ref variable from parent so when the submit button is clicked he could get the value and save modificacions. setContents is just working sometimes. When I save the project and is compiled again text appeared. But if I use the app or refresh the window text dissapear. I have checked that the variable still has the value. I'm new to React and I'm not sure If I'm doing it wrong or just suneditor-react failing. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
export const TranslationArea = React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>{    
    
    const handleEditorChange = (value) => {
        console.log(value);  
    
        ref.current= value;
      }
     const handleClick  = () => {
         console.log(ref.current);
     } 
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                <SunEditor 
                    autoFocus={true}
                    width="100%"
                    height="150px"
                    setOptions={{
                        buttonList: [
                            // default
                            ['undo', 'redo'],
                            ['bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'list'],
                            ['table', 'link', 'image'],
                            ['fullScreen']
                        ]
                    
                    }}
                    setContents={props.content}
                    onChange={handleEditorChange}
            
                />
                <div>{props.content}</div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Content</button>
        </div>
    );
});
```

Here is the screenshot with content properly loaded inside SunEditor div (only when compiling project):
[image]

If I refresh the page or navigate to the same link...
[image]

I have displayed a div with the same props.content just to check that fowardRef is working. Why setContents is now working? I have inspect with React tools and the property is loaded:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm passing a ref variable from parent so when the submit button is clicked he could get the value and save modifications.

If all you need to access is the value, let's pass down a callback instead.  We'll call it `onSumbit` and it will be a function which takes the `string` value from the `SunEditor` component.

In order to have access to the current edited value, I am using a local state in the `TranslationArea` component and updating that state through the editor's `onChange` method.  Then when the submit button is clicked, I call `onSubmit` with the value of `content` from the local state. (There might be another way to do this but I'm not familiar with SunEditor).

The `TranslationArea` component looks like this:

```
export const TranslationArea = ({initialContent = "", title, onSubmit}) => {    
  const [content, setContent] = useState(initialContent);

  return(
      <div>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
              <SunEditor 
                  autoFocus={true}
                  width="100%"
                  height="150px"
                  setOptions={{
                      buttonList: [
                          // default
                          ['undo', 'redo'],
                          ['bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'list'],
                          ['table', 'link', 'image'],
                          ['fullScreen']
                      ]
                  
                  }}
                  setContents={initialContent}
                  onChange={setContent}
              />
              <div>{content}</div>
          <button onClick={() => onSubmit(content)}>Submit</button>
      </div>
  );
};
```

I tested it in my CodeSandbox by giving it an `onSubmit` function which logs the submitted content, but you can do whatever you need to with it.

```
export default function App() {
  const initialContent = "Hello World";
  const onSubmit = (content: string) => {
    console.log("Submitted Content", content);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TranslationArea
        initialContent={initialContent}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        title="Edit Text"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64349295-e6h98?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: This helped me to solve the problem. However, I don't understand why you cannot use initialContent directly from parent and a new state variable needs to be created. Could you explain that? I've tried passing my parent state variable and its setter (like the onSubmit function) but didn't work. Btw I finally had to handle initialContent with useRef() in parent so the whole component does not refresh when user type on editor. Thanks for helping me reach the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
const [content,setContent] = useState('');
var initialContent = YOUR_PROPS_FROM_DB_STATE;
```

In SunEditor Component:

```
<SunEditor 
defaultValue={initialContent}
setContents={YOUR_PROPS_FROM_DB_STATE}
placeholder={placeholder}
onChange={setContent}
/>
```

In my case YOUR_PROPS_FROM_DB is state comes from parent component.
placeholder - any variable or string inside. Sure that is not the best solution. But somehow it works.

Hope this helps!
Regards,