# Reactjs - CKEditor onchange lift up state

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I manage to set up CKEditor and it works great. My problem is I'm refactoring the code and I need the editor component to be called by several other components.

So, my handleChange is not really working anymore. How can I pass only data to parent's handleChange function?

parent:

```
function IncluirArtigo() {

    const campos = { autor: '', titulo: '', texto: '' };

    const [valores, setValores] = useState(campos);
    const [erro, setErro] = useState(false);
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleChange = e => {
        setValores({
            ...valores,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        console.log(valores)
    }

    const incluir = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(valores);
        
        try {
            //await PostArtigo(valores);
            /* Poderia redirecionar para o artigo criado, se o post retornasse uma id */
            goHome();
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error('erro', e);
            setErro(true);
        }
    }

    const goHome = () => history.push('/');

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {
                erro ?
                    <div>Houve erro na inclusão do artigo, tente novamente</div>
                    :
                    <>
                        <h3>Inclusão de Artigos</h3>
                        <form onSubmit={incluir} className="form-incluir">
                            <label htmlFor="autor">Autor:</label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="autor" 
                                value={valores.autor}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor="titulo">Título:</label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="titulo" 
                                value={valores.titulo}
                                onChange={handleChange}    
                                />
                            <label>Conteúdo:</label>
                            <div className="editor">
                                <Editor />
                            </div>
                            <input className="btn-enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
                        </form>
                    </>
            }
        </div >
    )
}
```

editor.js

```
function Editor() {

    return (
        <div className="editor">
            <CKEditor
                editor={ClassicEditor}
                data={valores.texto}
                onChange={(event, editor) => {
                    const texto = editor.getData();
                    console.log({ event, editor, texto });
                    handleChange() /* I need this function to pass only valores data */
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You want to make this a controlled component where the value of the editor content is stored and updated in the parent.  I'll look at the package docs and see if I can edit your code.  I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349295/setcontents-suneditor-is-not-working-react) about SunEditor a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Parent Controls the Text

We can make the editor into a controlled component by passing down the value from the parent and also using an `onChange` callback to update the value in the parent.

```
function Editor({ texto, onChangeTexto }) {
  return (
    <div className="editor">
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data={texto}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          onChangeTexto(editor.getData());
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
<Editor
  texto={valores.texto}
  onChangeTexto={(texto) => {
    setValores({ ...valores, texto });
  }}
/>
```

### Method 2: Parent Accesses Editor Instance

The `CKEditor` component has a prop called `onInit` which we can use to pass a refence to the `editor` object to the parent.  Instead of updating the state on every change, the parent can get the value of the text from `editor.getData()` rather than from `valores.texto`.

```
function Editor({ onInit }) {
  return (
    <div className="editor">
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        onInit={onInit}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In parent:

```
const [editor, setEditor] = useState(null);
```

```
<Editor
  onInit={setEditor}
/>
```

To get text ( in submit function )

```
const texto = editor?.getData();
```

In this particular case I would probably go with Method 2 as it limits the amount of state changes and re-renders.